# Weird tabindex issue in safari mobile

Tags: html, button, usability, tabindex

Is it possible to give a `<button></button>` a tabindex value and make it focusable in 
 **Safari Mobile?** Im facing this very weird issue on the site i'm working on where you have a few: 
 `<select></select>` options **Which a user can tab through just fine.** **However they are not able to tab to the `<button></button>`** (which is the next element in the DOM) instead it tabs to the next `<input>` field. So I'm starting to come to the conclusion that the  element isn't focusable or something.

I was thinking maybe the best solution would be to give the `<input>` after the `<select>` a tabindex of -1 so the user can't tab after the last field.

Any suggestions would be great? Or if there is a way to make the `<button>` element tab navigatable in safari I would love to hear how you got this to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This would be possible with both JQuery and JavaScript. I can only give a JS example for now (I will work on a JQuery one if you wish).

Basicly, you find the tab/button that is selected, and you find the next one. INFO: You will need to have a function that either A) sets a global variable `tabid` to the current tab id when clicked, or B) have each tab inidividualy set the variable `tabid` to a custom value.

```
document.getElementBydId("idOfYourNav").onkeydown = function(event) {
    var tabs = ["idoftab1","idoftab2","idoftab3","idoftab1"]  
    if(event.keyCode==9) {                     // check to see if the key was a tab key
        event.preventDefault()                 // prevent the browser from navigating out of the nav.
        var oldId = tabid                      // get the oldid
        var oldindex = tabs.indexOf(oldid)     // get first occurrence of old id
        var newindex = oldindex+1              //get the new index
        var newid = tabs[newindex]             // get next id
        document.getElementById(newid).focus() // focus that tab
    }
}

function settab(tab){
    tabid=tab
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <div id="idOfYourNav">
        <button id="tab1" onclick="settab('tab1')"></button>
        <button id="tab2" onclick="settab('tab2')"></button>
        <button id="tab3" onclick="settab('tab3')"></button>
    </div>
</html>
```

```js
    document.getElementById("idOfYourNav").onkeydown = function(event) {
    
        var tabs = ["tab1","tab2","tab3","tab1"]  
        if(event.keyCode==9) { 
        event.preventDefault()                    // check to see if the key was a tab key
            var oldId = tabid                      // get the oldid
            var oldindex = tabs.indexOf(oldId)     // get first occurrence of old id
            var newindex = oldindex+1              //get the new index
            var newid = tabs[newindex]             // get next id
            console.log(newid)
            document.getElementById(newid).focus() // focus that tab
            tabid=newid
        }
    }

    function settab(tab){
        tabid=tab
    }
```

```html
<html>
        <div id="idOfYourNav">
            <button id="tab1" onclick="settab('tab1')">tab1</button>
            <button id="tab2" onclick="settab('tab2')">tab2</button>
            <button id="tab3" onclick="settab('tab3')">tab3</button>
        </div>
    </html>
```

Comment: unfortunately if you do `shift + tab` you still navigate forward.